# Can I Change torchvision.transform.Lambda to normal function?

Tags: python, lambda, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

```
rand_crop = transforms.Lambda(
        lambda x: crop(x) if random.random() < prob else x)
```

This is a part of Code. I think, the lambda function makes a error. So, I want to change that part to normal? function. Is it possible? or It has speciallities?

(Sorry, I can't find the jargon about non-lambda function like print("hello") If you know, please tell me.)